# How to convert symbolic expressions to float in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, sympy

Now i m trying to solve 6th order of nonlinear equations.

For solving this problem, 'fsolve' is the best module for my situation.

But i have a problem for using this 'fsolve'.

My Equations below : eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5, eq6

```
U = (E*h/32)*(pi**4*K3+8*pi**2*K4+16*J2-pi**4/b*K1**2-8*pi**2/b*K1*J1)+pi**2/2*D*((K1*K2)**0.5+(1-v)*K5-v*K6)+F/(4*b)*pi**2*K1
    
eq1 = diff(U,b_1)

eq2 = diff(U,b_2)

eq3 = diff(U,b_3)

eq4 = diff(U,b_4)

eq5 = diff(U,b_5)

eq6 = diff(U,b_6)
```

Now i m gonna try to define functions:

```
def functions(v):
       
    b_1 = v[0]     
    b_2 = v[1]    
    b_3 = v[2]   
    b_4 = v[3]    
    b_5 = v[4] 
    b_6 = v[5]
       
    return eq1,eq2,eq3,eq4,eq5,eq6
```

Until now, all of code is perfectly completed.

But next, I got a error code for 'fsolve'

```
x0 = [0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1]

solutions = fsolve(functions,x0)


Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sympy\core\expr.py", line 327, in __float__
    raise TypeError("can't convert expression to float")

TypeError: can't convert expression to float

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\-----\trial.py", line 97, in <module>
    solutions = fsolve(functions,x0)

  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 147, in fsolve
    res = _root_hybr(func, x0, args, jac=fprime, **options)

  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 225, in _root_hybr
    ml, mu, epsfcn, factor, diag)

error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats.
```

Actually i don't know exactly meaning about 'array of floats'.

The eq1~eq6 is really complicated expressions. For example (eq1):

```
519749583.393768*b_1**3 + 519749583.393768*b_1**2*b_2 + 311849750.036261*b_1**2*b_3 + 222749821.454472*b_1**2*b_4 + 173249861.131256*b_1**2*b_5 + 141749886.380119*b_1**2*b_6 + 589049527.846271*b_1*b_2**2 + 920699262.011818*b_1*b_2*b_3 + 742499404.84824*b_1*b_2*b_4 + 619499503.439037*b_1*b_2*b_5 + 530653420.807624*b_1*b_2*b_6 + 395009683.379264*b_1*b_3**2 + 672299461.117134*b_1*b_3*b_4 + 581053380.409443*b_1*b_3*b_5 + 510299590.968427*b_1*b_3*b_6 + 296183828.527375*b_1*b_4**2 + 524699579.42609*b_1*b_4*b_5 + 469323153.224931*b_1*b_4*b_6 + 236661575.009363*b_1*b_5**2 + 429394392.660243*b_1*b_5*b_6 + 196977114.839905*b_1*b_6**2 + 39642.9110110422*b_1 + 193049845.260542*b_2**3 + 482129613.548124*b_2**2*b_3 + 406949673.808743*b_2**2*b_4 + 350618949.729969*b_2**2*b_5 + 307488215.070719*b_2**2*b_6 + 420149663.228267*b_2*b_3**2 + 732095017.5835*b_2*b_3*b_4 + 645437944.186494*b_2*b_3*b_5 + 575987321.121736*b_2*b_3*b_6 + 326318969.207663*b_2*b_4**2 + 585464236.60242*b_2*b_4*b_5 + 529609601.687166*b_2*b_4*b_6 + 266189415.118358*b_2*b_5**2 + 486862510.0121*b_2*b_5*b_6 + 224616040.694387*b_2*b_6**2 - 29192.3833775011*b_2 + 125272976.510293*b_3**3 + 334349732.001359*b_3**2*b_4 + 299655189.675087*b_3**2*b_5 + 270932940.727941*b_3**2*b_6 + 302393649.018531*b_3*b_4**2 + 549176644.826696*b_3*b_4*b_5 + 501838635.183477*b_3*b_4*b_6 + 252001834.206563*b_3*b_5**2 + 464613445.578031*b_3*b_5*b_6 + 215729827.081362*b_3*b_6**2 - 28558.195613361*b_3 + 92286363.2746599*b_4**3 + 253972873.350655*b_4**2*b_5 + 234063996.922265*b_4**2*b_6 + 234970783.525745*b_4*b_5**2 + 436229928.976872*b_4*b_5*b_6 + 203716223.26551*b_4*b_6**2 - 24903.5955817128*b_4 + 72968765.0411644*b_5**3 + 204424758.743579*b_5**2*b_6 + 191897759.069662*b_5*b_6**2 - 21706.6337724143*b_5 + 60314467.7838601*b_6**3 - 19178.52782655*b_6 + 52.9828871992195*((35.720610813872*b_2**2 + 142.882443255488*b_2*b_3 + 214.323664883232*b_2*b_4 + 285.764886510976*b_2*b_5 + 357.20610813872*b_2*b_6 + 257.188397859878*b_3**2 + 918.529992356708*b_3*b_4 + 1333.56947038455*b_3*b_5 + 1753.55725813553*b_3*b_6 + 893.0152703468*b_4**2 + 2727.7557348775*b_4*b_5 + 3709.44804605594*b_4*b_6 + 2154.22760600582*b_5**2 + 6001.0626167305*b_5*b_6 + 4254.9551116524*b_6**2)*(0.482*b_1**2 + 0.321333333333333*b_1*b_2 + 0.1928*b_1*b_3 + 0.137714285714286*b_1*b_4 + 0.107111111111111*b_1*b_5 + 0.0876363636363637*b_1*b_6 + 0.0964*b_2**2 + 0.137714285714286*b_2*b_3 + 0.107111111111111*b_2*b_4 + 0.0876363636363637*b_2*b_5 + 0.0741538461538462*b_2*b_6 + 0.0535555555555556*b_3**2 + 0.0876363636363637*b_3*b_4 + 0.0741538461538462*b_3*b_5 + 0.0642666666666667*b_3*b_6 + 0.0370769230769231*b_4**2 + 0.0642666666666667*b_4*b_5 + 0.0567058823529412*b_4*b_6 + 0.0283529411764706*b_5**2 + 0.0507368421052632*b_5*b_6 + 0.022952380952381*b_6**2))**0.5*(0.964*b_1 + 0.321333333333333*b_2 + 0.1928*b_3 + 0.137714285714286*b_4 + 0.107111111111111*b_5 + 0.0876363636363637*b_6)/(0.482*b_1**2 + 0.321333333333333*b_1*b_2 + 0.1928*b_1*b_3 + 0.137714285714286*b_1*b_4 + 0.107111111111111*b_1*b_5 + 0.0876363636363637*b_1*b_6 + 0.0964*b_2**2 + 0.137714285714286*b_2*b_3 + 0.107111111111111*b_2*b_4 + 0.0876363636363637*b_2*b_5 + 0.0741538461538462*b_2*b_6 + 0.0535555555555556*b_3**2 + 0.0876363636363637*b_3*b_4 + 0.0741538461538462*b_3*b_5 + 0.0642666666666667*b_3*b_6 + 0.0370769230769231*b_4**2 + 0.0642666666666667*b_4*b_5 + 0.0567058823529412*b_4*b_6 + 0.0283529411764706*b_5**2 + 0.0507368421052632*b_5*b_6 + 0.022952380952381*b_6**2) + (-1.28102213260338e-7*b_2 - 3.20255533150846e-8*b_3 - 3.20255533150846e-8*b_4 - 1.60127766575423e-8*b_6)*(0.482*b_1**2 + 0.321333333333333*b_1*b_2 + 0.1928*b_1*b_3 + 0.137714285714286*b_1*b_4 + 0.107111111111111*b_1*b_5 + 0.0876363636363637*b_1*b_6 + 0.0964*b_2**2 + 0.137714285714286*b_2*b_3 + 0.107111111111111*b_2*b_4 + 0.0876363636363637*b_2*b_5 + 0.0741538461538462*b_2*b_6 + 0.0535555555555556*b_3**2 + 0.0876363636363637*b_3*b_4 + 0.0741538461538462*b_3*b_5 + 0.0642666666666667*b_3*b_6 + 0.0370769230769231*b_4**2 + 0.0642666666666667*b_4*b_5 + 0.0567058823529412*b_4*b_6 + 0.0283529411764706*b_5**2 + 0.0507368421052632*b_5*b_6 + 0.022952380952381*b_6**2) + (1.18477228028269e-9*b_1 + 6.14508444130024e-10*b_2 + 4.60881333097518e-10*b_3 + 1.53627111032506e-10*b_4 + 1.53627111032506e-10*b_5)*(78.9568352087149*b_1**2 + 52.6378901391433*b_1*b_2 + 31.582734083486*b_1*b_3 + 22.5590957739185*b_1*b_4 + 17.5459633797144*b_1*b_5 + 14.3557882197663*b_1*b_6 + 15.791367041743*b_2**2 + 22.5590957739185*b_2*b_3 + 17.5459633797144*b_2*b_4 + 14.3557882197663*b_2*b_5 + 12.1472054167254*b_2*b_6 + 8.77298168985721*b_3**2 + 14.3557882197663*b_3*b_4 + 12.1472054167254*b_3*b_5 + 10.5275780278287*b_3*b_6 + 6.07360270836269*b_4**2 + 10.5275780278287*b_4*b_5 + 9.2890394363194*b_4*b_6 + 4.6445197181597*b_5**2 + 8.31124581144368*b_5*b_6 + 3.75984929565309*b_6**2) + (0.964*b_1 + 0.321333333333333*b_2 + 0.1928*b_3 + 0.137714285714286*b_4 + 0.107111111111111*b_5 + 0.0876363636363637*b_6)*(-1.28102213260338e-7*b_1*b_2 - 3.20255533150846e-8*b_1*b_3 - 3.20255533150846e-8*b_1*b_4 - 1.60127766575423e-8*b_1*b_6 - 1.60127766575423e-8*b_2**2 - 3.20255533150846e-8*b_2*b_3 - 1.60127766575423e-8*b_2*b_5 - 8.00638832877115e-9*b_3**2 + 1.60127766575423e-8*b_3*b_4 - 8.00638832877115e-9*b_3*b_6 - 8.00638832877115e-9*b_4*b_5 + 8.00638832877115e-9*b_4*b_6 + 4.00319416438558e-9*b_5**2 - 8.00638832877115e-9*b_5*b_6 + 4.00319416438558e-9*b_6**2 + 41123.3516712057) - 129937395.848442*(4*b_1 + 1.33333333333333*b_2 + 0.8*b_3 + 0.571428571428572*b_4 + 0.444444444444445*b_5 + 0.363636363636364*b_6)*(b_1**2 + 0.666666666666667*b_1*b_2 + 0.4*b_1*b_3 + 0.285714285714286*b_1*b_4 + 0.222222222222222*b_1*b_5 + 0.181818181818182*b_1*b_6 + 0.2*b_2**2 + 0.285714285714286*b_2*b_3 + 0.222222222222222*b_2*b_4 + 0.181818181818182*b_2*b_5 + 0.153846153846154*b_2*b_6 + 0.111111111111111*b_3**2 + 0.181818181818182*b_3*b_4 + 0.153846153846154*b_3*b_5 + 0.133333333333333*b_3*b_6 + 0.076923076923077*b_4**2 + 0.133333333333333*b_4*b_5 + 0.117647058823529*b_4*b_6 + 0.0588235294117647*b_5**2 + 0.105263157894737*b_5*b_6 + 0.0476190476190477*b_6**2) + (157.91367041743*b_1 + 52.6378901391433*b_2 + 31.582734083486*b_3 + 22.5590957739185*b_4 + 17.5459633797144*b_5 + 14.3557882197663*b_6)*(5.92386140141343e-10*b_1**2 + 6.14508444130024e-10*b_1*b_2 + 4.60881333097518e-10*b_1*b_3 + 1.53627111032506e-10*b_1*b_4 + 1.53627111032506e-10*b_1*b_5 + 2.30440666548759e-10*b_2**2 + 1.53627111032506e-10*b_2*b_3 + 1.53627111032506e-10*b_2*b_4 + 1.53627111032506e-10*b_2*b_6 + 7.6813555516253e-11*b_3**2 - 7.6813555516253e-11*b_3*b_4 + 7.6813555516253e-11*b_3*b_6 + 7.6813555516253e-11*b_4*b_5 + 7.6813555516253e-11*b_4*b_6 + 3.84067777581265e-11*b_5**2 - 251.041666666667)
```

I must solve such theses 6 equations.

But " Result from function call is not a proper array of floats. " error message comes out.

Is there anyone who help my code?

I'm Python beginning, so Plz understane me

Comment: Who or what told you `scipy's` `fsolve` was the best tool?  It's not the right tool if it doesn't work.  Trying to use `sympy` and `scipy` together is not a task for a Python beginner.  `scipy/numpy` is a numerical package, and doesn't 'know' anything about `sympy` symbols or functions.  But if you must use them together, use `sympy.lambdify` to make a numpy compatible function.

Comment: You probably want to use sympy's `nsolve`: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html#sympy.solvers.solvers.nsolve